# iCloud mail not notifying on iPhone

Tags: iphone, icloud, mail.app, gmail

I'm using iCloud mail, and everything is connected just fine. I have a Mac with the stock Mac Mail app, and I receive messages very quickly after they're sent, like normal.

On my iPhone (8 with OS 15.0.2), I can get messages when I open the app, but no notifications. I've re-checked every setting, turned all of them off and back on, still nothing. I've powered the phone off and on, and even factory-reset the phone, still not working.

Earlier, I wanted to give the Gmail app a try as the client, logging in with an App Password. And that one also does not get mail notifications for iCloud - I'll give it half an hour, no notifications, then open the app and all the messages immediately come in. I did the same with this app as the stock app - turning notifications off/on the in-app settings, the phone's notification settings, background app refresh, everything, and still no notifications there either. It does give notifications for messages in my Gmail account, so the app notifications are ok.

I tried one more - Edison Mail, and the funny thing there is that it's pushing out notifications practically instantly - which I didn't think was possible for a non-stock mail app. But that seems to tell me that the IMAP server is ok. It's just the stock Mail app and the Gmail app.

Any ideas on how to kick this thing so I get notifications back on either the stock or Gmail apps? Other than the standard "uninstall and reinstall", double check settings, etc., since I've already done all that multiple times.

Comment: In Settings > Mail > Accounts what is "Fetch New Data" set to?

Comment: I’ve had it on every combination, but I usually have Push on, iCloud set to Push, and Fetch set to Automatically, but I tried 15 minutes as well. Nothing ever makes a difference. Even with everything set to Fetch, I get icon overlays showing new messages but no notifications.

Comment: Another round of turning various settings off and on, and it seems to be working now.